# How to add Hyperlink to column in gridview1?

Tags: gridview

i have gridview and wanna make the first column (ID) as hyper link when i click on any ID of students moving to the second page and displays data in Textbox .

this is my code ....

First Page name called (Default)

Html code

```
   <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
   </asp:Content>
   <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
   onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   </asp:GridView>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
   Text="Add New Student" Width="118px" />
  </asp:Content>
```

Backhand code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet s = new DataSet();
    s.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("Courses.xml"));
    GridView1.DataSource= s.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int gridrowscount = GridView1.Rows.Count;//getting grid view rows count to assign as id to the next 
    Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?ID="+gridrowscount); // open new Page and transfering the count using querystring


}
```

Second Page called (Default2)

backhand code

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    int intID;// declaring global variable to ust it anywhere 
    string ID;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        intID = int.Parse(Request.Params["ID"]) + 1;//to increase the int that coming from first page 1
        ID = intID.ToString();

```
}
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet dsXML = new DataSet();
    dsXML.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "Courses.xml");
    if (dsXML.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow drstudent = dsXML.Tables[0].NewRow();
        drstudent["ID"] = Server.HtmlEncode(ID);
        drstudent["Name"] = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
        drstudent["Email"] = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text);
        drstudent["Address"] = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox3.Text);
        drstudent["Mobile"] = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox4.Text);
        drstudent["Class"] = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox5.Text);

        dsXML.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drstudent);
    }

        dsXML.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "Courses.xml");
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");

         }

private void BindData()
{
    XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("Courses.xml"));
    xmlReader.Close();
}

}
```

xml Element code

```
 <Students>
   <Student>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <Name>ahmad</Name>
     <Address>amman</Address>
     <Mobile>909999999</Mobile>
     <Class>Fourth</Class>
    </Student>
  </Students>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the first column of the gridview an `<asp:LinkButton>` with the text parameter as  `Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'`.